# How to check the size of a set in drools rules

Tags: drools

I have the following rule in drool

```
rule klFor2001 salience 30
when
 exists( Vgdokfag( Fagkode() == "FOR2001", ( Merknadkode() != "FAM13" ||
                   Merknadparameter() in ("FO1010", "FO1030", "FO1040"))))
 vgs: HashSet() from collect(Vgdokfag( Fagkode() contains "UPF",
                                 (Merknadkode() == "FAM13" ||
                                 Merknadparameter() in ("FO1010","FO1030", "FO1040"))) )
                                      
then
  insert(getKlIdr20xx("KL_IDR2001",true));
end
```

So what I am trying to do is to

1. check if there is a *Vgdokfag* with *For2001* as *Fagkode* and with either *Merknadkode* not equal to "FAM13" or *Merknadparameter* is one of the following strings ("FO1010","FO1030", "FO1040").
2. check that there exist at least two *VgdokFag* facts which has "UPF" in their "Fagkode" and either *Merknadkode* is equal to "FAM13" or *Merknadparameter* is one of the following strings ("FO1010","FO1030", "FO1040").

I do not know how to do the second one. I am trying to get all facts with the given conditions and then some how check if the size of the set is bigger than 2, but for some reason I cannot write something like this

```
eval(vgs.size() > 2)
```

I am sure that I am doing something wrong here, can someone please help me.

cheers,

es

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were really close. You can add the `size` constraint straight into the `HashSet`:

```
vgs: HashSet(size >= 2) from collect(...)
```